# JavaScript: Append space (&nbsp;) after a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html

The DOM element is an html string as `<span></span>` and I need to add a space at the end of it, like this: `<span></span>&nbsp`.

When I do it like in the code below it returns an object `[object HTMLSpanElement]` on the element.

I'm using the element in a callback function as `callback : (emoji, category, node) => {}` and it adds an html span with a background image when I click on a button. I just want to add space at the end of it –

```
    var str =  node + '&nbsp';
    self.myHtmlCodeL = str;
```

Comment: You should use `element.innerText` or `element.innerHTML`

Comment: Do you wanna give us the full code you have? Just adding space does it. What's `myHtmlCodeL` anyway?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman i dont want to add a string to the DOM, im trying to add an html string together with a space at the end of it. I dont know how to append the space correctly

Comment: Oh, sorry! My bad! I don't know how to unflag it, so I just deleted my comment :s

Comment: So it's _after_ the `</span>`?

Comment: is this what you're looking for? `spanElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '&nsbp')`

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman it doesn't work cause i tried that one

Comment: Okay. Added it in an answer then :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Eh? "it doesn't work" --> "added it in an answer"...

Comment: @JoeIddon Sorry: `spanElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "&nbsp")` will work :)

Comment: Updated the answer too.

Comment: @JoeIddon he added it in an answer cause it may help others even though it didnt help me in my case

Comment: Why are you having a background image in a `<span>`? Surely you'd use a `<div>` and why do you want a space after the image? This doesn't make much sense as it stands.

Comment: @sara Ah, I see

Comment: @JoeIddon im using an emoji-picker library which adds the spans in an editable div. That's not my issue

Comment: @sara didn't the last code I gave work?

Comment: I forgot the semicolon. THIS will work as in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg72L139/3/) I created.
`spanElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "&nbsp;")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To append after the end of a DOM-object, you can do

```
spanElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "&nbsp;")
```

**EDIT**: Forgot a semicolon

Comment: im trying it and it says undefined on console. I'l try to find a workaround. Thanks a lot though :)

Comment: Look, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/cg72L139/4/

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `node` is an element. To append to its text, you need to use `node.innerText`:

```
var str = node.innerText + 'some more text';
another_node.innerText = str;
```

But if you want to add the special [`&nbsp`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), then you must use `node.innerHTML`:

```js
var node = document.getElementById('spn');
var str = node.innerHTML;
str += '&nbsp';
node.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<span id='spn'>start</span>end
```

Comment: this will actually add `&nbsp;` to the text : https://jsfiddle.net/eyvz2b0n/5/

Comment: @Taki See updated!

Comment: node.innerText it's still [object HTMLSpanElement]. i'm using node in a callback function as    callback  : (emoji, category, node) => {} and it adds an html span with a background image when i click on a button. I just want to add space at the end of it

Comment: @sara Please add these further details properly to the question (there is an edit button)